# Cronofy ics file smart invite not working

Tags: calendar, jakarta-mail, icalendar, cronofy

Hi I am using cronofy smart invites to create ics calendar file for scheduling meetings in my java applications
but when I cancel the meeting the ics file is not supported by outlook
its working fine for google and other clients.

the cancel ics file content is :

```
Event iCalendar in cancel :-
 "BEGIN:
VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Cronofy//Cronofy0.1//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200629T133045Z
UID:uid>@invite.cronofy.com
DTSTART:20200709T053000Z
DTEND:20200709T063000Z
DESCRIPTION:Calender test
LAST-MODIFIED:20200629T133000Z
LOCATION:Test Loaction\\, USA
ORGANIZER;CN=cooksmart Notification:mailto:DoNotReply@cooksmart.com
SEQUENCE:4
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:Calender test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:<myEmailId>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"
 
Event iCalender in create :- 
"BEGIN:
VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Cronofy//Cronofy 0.1//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200629T133014Z
UID:<uid>@invite.cronofy.com
DTSTART:20200709T053000Z
DTEND:20200709T063000Z
DESCRIPTION:Calender test
LAST-MODIFIED:20200629T133000Z
LOCATION:Test Loaction, USA
ORGANIZER;CN=cooksmart Notification:mailto:DoNotReply@cooksmart.com
SEQUENCE:3
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Calender test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;X-NUM -GUESTS=0;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:<myEmailId>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"
```

I have added header as

```
request.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
request.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
```

Comment: my cronofy UID is same in both cases also from address while sending create and cancel request is also same

Answer (score 0):

The ICS content looks valid, so it could be the format of the email it's attached to.

The [iMIP best practices](https://devguide.calconnect.org/Scheduling/iMIP/#best-practices) describe the best structure for iCalendar attachments to ensure they can be parsed by most email clients. Using that structure should help Outlook parse the email and attached ICS.

Edit: It's also worth looking at the [Cronofy documentation](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/smart-invites/sending/https://) about sending invites for some code examples, or contacting [Cronofy support](https://docs.cronofy.com/support/) directly.

Comment: I did try to change the email headers, sending mail by different ways, adding tzid in json which I am sending to cronofy to get tzid added into ics file which did not change the output though and  problem still persists I will contact the cronofy support directly thanks.